# ListView exception - The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, android-listview

I used listview to show content of an ArrayList named `numberlist` but sometimes this exception occurred `The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification` I used `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but still having the same problem, any idea?

onPostExecute of AsyncTask:

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), numberlist);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() whenever you change numberlist, or before your posted code?

It should be whenever numberlist changes.

Comment: I called this between above lines

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the relevant code? It sounds like you could be modifying the List associated with your Adapter off the UI thread somewhere.